# VLC does not stop after exiting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I am having a problem with vlc on xubuntu 15.04, which is vlc sometimes does not exit after I pressed the close button on the window. Still after closing the window, the vlc icon is still on the toolbar and I have to enter task manager and kill it. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I have this issue with other apps! I dont know for sure, but I think its because the app has became unstable or the app is hanging!

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on your keyboard to close VLC, otherwise its process will keep running.
Or click Media -> Quit (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal you can run:

```
pkill -9 vlc
```

Comment: This is just a way to kill the process, but does not answer why this happens, nor how can one solve it.